# Adding 100 buttons in a div

Tags: javascript

I am following along a Javascript tutorial and I have to add in 100 buttons inside of a `div` using Javascript.

At first, I tried doing something like this:

```
const btn = document.createElement('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');
btn.innerText = 'Hey!';
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    div.appendChild(btn);
}
```

And this ended up only making 1 button. However, if I repeat the same code it just appends buttons after the previous one. However, this approach:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    const div = document.querySelector('div');
    btn.innerText = 'Hey!';
    div.appendChild(btn);
}
```

does the job. I can't seem to understand why the 2nd one works and the 1st one doesn't.

From my understanding, the first approach seemed better because I wasn't making the same variables over and over again. However that only ends up in me making just one button instead of 100.

Comment: You're not creating a new button on each iteration in the first example.

Comment: it does not work because in the first example you create only one element, so when you do div.appendChild(btn) you just add the same btn again and again. Second example can be improved by putting the div outside of the loop

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier But isn't the `button` element reusable? If I have already created the element and stored it in `btn`, shouldn't I be able to reuse it? Because in the `for loop` I'm just iterating over and appending the already created `btn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that *creates* element is `document.createElement` and You call it ones in first example, hence only one element is *created*.

`appendChild` does not *creates* an element, it **appends** already created element to some parent.

If it is already appended, then does nothing

Answer (score 3):

First example won't work, cause it is just how method `appendChild` works. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). It just moves the node/element from its current position to specified. So your first example is just *renewing* the position of only one node, cause you've created *only one* `div`

Second example creates `div` every time, so it is a new element, which is stored inside your parent element.

Answer (score 1):

because in the first case you are trying to append the same DOM object 100 times, but have to create a new one each time

Answer (score 0):

I doing the same one. I looked at it as make one button you have to do

```
const btn = document.createElement('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');
btn.innerText = 'Hey!';
div.appendChild(btn);
```

to make the other 99 you have to rewrite the whole code 99 more times, so that's why you wrap everything inside the loop